# SharePoint Integration with Team Foundation Server

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, central-administration, installation, tfs

I am attemping to get SharePoint Portal integrations on Team Foundation Server 2010 x86 running with a standard single server installation on a WinServer w SP2.  I can provide any and all information but I believe there is a permissions issue somewhere.

Error:

> [2012-08-06 23:23:54Z][Error] TF252031: A SharePoint site could not be
>   created for the team project collection. The following error occurred:
>   TF250034: An access grant could not be found between Team Foundation
>   Server and the SharePoint Web application that you specified. The Team
>   Foundation Server ID is: db1d4655-f543-4709-b8e9-306410088558. The
>   SharePoint Web application is:
>       `http://prod01/sites/test6`.
>
> You must
>   grant access for the Web application in the Team Foundation
>   Administration Console.

I also noticed in the Central Administration site there is a server service, "Windows SharePoint Services Search ", not running.  When trying to start the service I'm directed to a service configuration page that I have filled 100x using domain credentials for the service account (same username for both the service account and the content access account, windows authentication for the SQL account)

I receive the following error:

> "Error    SPSearch (_tfssvcprod)  Troubleshoot issues with Windows
>   SharePoint Services.   "

which is not particularly helpful.  I am not sure how to proceed at this point.

----EDIT----
In reference to @C. Marius comment's:

1. Confirmed.
2. Don't believe this to be true regarding SP Extensions on a single server instance.

> If you want to use a deployment of SharePoint Products that is on a different server, 
>   you must install the Team Foundation Server extensions for SharePoint Products on > that > server or servers. [Interactions Between SharePoint Products and Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253177%28VS.100%29.aspx)
>    
>   
>   2  cont.  I see SP in TFS under "SharePoint Web Applications"   Username _TfsSvcProd listed under "Service Accounts for SharePoint Web Applications"  This user is also a member of the Farm Administrators Group.

3 Creating a new project does not prompt for creation of a portal.

--- 2nd Edit ---

With Team Foundation Server Administration Console, in PROD01 | Application Tier | SharePoint Web Applications I do see  an application listed with the proper URL.  I clicked "Repair Connections" and receive the following error message:

> Reconnecting SharePoint Web application at the following address: .
>   [Warning] TF205018: An error occurred when attempting to save the mapping from the SharePoint Web application to Team Foundation Server. The SharePoint Web application is: . The error is: TF250067: No connection could be made to Team Foundation Server at the following address: :8080/tfs. Either the specified URL does not point to a server that is running Team Foundation Server, the server is not available, or the service account for SharePoint Products does not have sufficient permissions on that server. The service account for SharePoint Products might not have been added to the required group in Team Foundation Server. For more information, see the Microsoft Web site (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161206)..
>   [Error] Team Foundation services are not available from server :8080/tfs.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>     HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable
>   Reconnect operation failed with warnings and/or errors

Comment: Are your TFS and SharePoint installations on the same machine? Is your TFS service account a Farm Administrator for SharePoint? I'm not familiar with the Search service, so I can't help there, but I don't think the two issues are related. (I would post this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep on this SE)

Comment: I believe they are see "Single server build", but you are right Search has nothing to do with it, rather TFS Service not being SharePoint Farm Admin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error connecting SP 2013 and TFS 2012](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45051/error-connecting-sp-2013-and-tfs-2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Russ said you would need to make sure that:

1. TFS Service account is in the Farm Administrators group also you
   could additionally add that user via User Policy as a FULL CONTROL
   (without "Run as System")
2. You have installed the SharePoint Extensions on the SharePoint machine (which i believe is the same as TFS from your message). Make sure you also find 2 solution packages for TFS in Central Administration. You would need to install manually if automatic these do not work.
3. Open TFS Console and specify an existent Web Application plus a Site Collection where you would like to store project sites.

Comment: 1.  Confirmed. 
2.  Don't believe this to be true regarding SP Extensions on a single server instance.
>If you want to use a deployment of SharePoint Products >that is on a different server, you must install the Team >Foundation Server extensions for SharePoint Products on > that server or servers. [Ref1][1]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253177(VS.100).aspx

Comment: starting from the question i've assumed that is where you try to get it running.

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?